8086 Assembly program to Input and Print string Not Working
I am using emu8086 to write this program to input and print the string I have typed. When I run it It takes the input string but does not print it. Here is the code.
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
var1 db 100 dup('$')
.code
main proc
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
mov si,offset var1

l1:
mov ah,1
int 21h
cmp al,13
je programend
mov [si],al
inc si
jmp l1

programend:
mov dx,10
mov ah,2
int 21h
mov dx, offset var1
mov ah,9
int 21h
mov ah,4ch
int 21h

main endp
end main

I have tried the lea (load effective address) to point the address of the string but still the same result.

It does get printed, it just overwrites the same characters so you don't see it.

@Jester Oh thanks for letting me know I'm new here actually this was my first question. Thank U Very much

You should print a newline character (code 10) to move to the next line. The carriage return is already included (code 13).

@Jester Got that! thnx again
